# Counting comparisons with heap-sort

Tags: python, count, heap

I have got the following code for `heap_sort`. I need to count the number of comparisons, but don't get the expected results.

This is the `heap_sort` code, with additional statements to accumulate and return a `count`:

```
def max_heapify(a, n, i):
    count = 0
    l, r = 2*i+1, 2*i+2
    largest = i
    if l < n and a[l] > a[largest]:
        largest = l
    if r < n and a[r] > a[largest]:
        largest = r
    if largest != i:
        a[i], a[largest] = a[largest], a[i]
        count += 1
        count += max_heapify(a, n, largest)
    count += 3
    return count


def build_max_heap(a):
    n = len(a)
    count = 0
    for i in range(n//2-1, -1, -1):
        count += max_heapify(a, n, i)
    return count


def heap_sort(a):
    n = len(a)
    count = build_max_heap(a)
    for i in range(n-1, 0, -1):
        a[0], a[i] = a[i], a[0]
        count += 1
        count += max_heapify(a, i, 0)
    return count
```

When calling:

```
lst = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
print(heap_sort(lst))
```

...the output should be 41, but instead I get 135

Where does my counting go wrong?

Comment: I updated your question, specifying that it is about counting **comparisons** (not "elements"). Please check this edit to see that it corresponds to what you intended to ask.

Answer (score 0):

For your example input it is indeed expected that the number of **comparisons** is 41.

But in reality your code *also* counts:

- swaps
- comparisons of *indices* `largest` and `i` -- which are not input data.
- comparisons that never happened. The expression in `if l < n and a[l] > a[largest]:` provides for short-circuit evaluation, meaning that if `l >= n`, then the second part of that expression is skipped, and so it shouldn't add to the count

None of the above should be counted. Only comparisons of values in the input list should be counted.

Here is the correction of your code:

```
def max_heapify(a, n, i):
    count = 0
    l, r = 2*i+1, 2*i+2
    largest = i
    if l < n:
        if a[l] > a[largest]:
            largest = l
        count += 1  # Only count when data comparison actually happened
    if r < n:
        if a[r] > a[largest]:
            largest = r
        count += 1  # Only count when data comparison actually happened
    if largest != i:  # This comparison does not count!
        a[i], a[largest] = a[largest], a[i]  # Don't count swaps
        count += max_heapify(a, n, largest)
    return count


def build_max_heap(a):
    n = len(a)
    count = 0
    for i in range(n//2-1, -1, -1):
        count += max_heapify(a, n, i)
    return count


def heap_sort(a):
    n = len(a)
    count = build_max_heap(a)
    for i in range(n-1, 0, -1):
        a[0], a[i] = a[i], a[0]  # Don't count swaps
        count += max_heapify(a, i, 0)
    return count
```

When running this:

```
lst = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
print(heap_sort(lst))
```

The output is 41.